# How to access image from assets folder to javascript object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi everyone I've situation while uploading image in **Angular project** if user doesn't select image then i want to ***read image from the assets folder and send it to backend***. after hours of trial and error. i'm not able to read the image from the asset folder to a JavaScript file object. if anyone knows please guide to me. Thanks in advance.

Things i've tried

1. I've tried to fetch it using **HttpClient** in Angular by passing relative path.
2. I've tried to create file object by passing relative path to **File(url)**;  constructor with no luck.

please help me.

**My problem is to create a file object by accessing the image from asset folder in the angular(4/5) project.**

Comment: You could google "Ajax file upload" and apply that.

Comment: @Martijn can you suggest how to access file from assets folder to Component or Service in angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the answer it works irrespective of any JavaScript framework.

```
var blob = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET", './assets/<FILENAME>'); 
xhr.responseType = "blob";//force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
xhr.onload = function() 
{
    blob = xhr.response;//xhr.response is now a blob object
    var file = new File([blob], 'logo.png', {type: 'image/png', lastModified: Date.now()});
    console.log(file);   
}
xhr.send()
}
```

For More Details:-
http://qnimate.com/javascript-create-file-object-from-url/

Answer (score 0):

To access your assets from javascript you need to mark your resource as trusted using [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) :

```
constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   const sanitizedUrl = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/<YOUR_IMAGE>');
}
```

From [Angular Security](https://angular.io/guide/security#angulars-cross-site-scripting-security-model)
Why :

> To systematically block XSS bugs, Angular treats all values as untrusted by default. When a value is inserted into the DOM from a template, via property, attribute, style, class binding, or interpolation, Angular sanitizes and escapes untrusted values.

[How to by pass when trusted.](https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis)

Comment: Can you provide some explanation about how it works?

Comment: Ok i got it, but how can  i create file object with this sanitized url any idea?